# Delete spaces php

Tags: php, trim, spaces

I need delete all tags from string and make it without spaces.

I have string

```
"<span class="left_corner"> </span><span class="text">Adv</span><span class="right_corner"> </span>"
```

After using strip_tags I get string

```
" Adv "
```

Using trim function I can`t delete spaces.

JSON string looks like "\u00a0...\u00a0".

Help me please delete this spaces.

Comment: Are you using trim before or after stripping the tags?

Comment: Those problematic characters are called "non breaking spaces".
The solution Oskar wrote should work (using preg_replace).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solution of this problem

`$str = trim($str, chr(0xC2).chr(0xA0))`

Comment: This one is the only one that truly worked for me. My string had some odd spacing characters!

Comment: This solution is not multibyte-safe, it will break encoding of your UTF8 strings (see my answer to the question).

Answer (score 4):

You should use `preg_replace()`, to make it in multibyte-safe way.

```
$str = preg_replace('/^[\s\x00]+|[\s\x00]+$/u', '', $str);
```

*Notes*:

- this will fix initial @Андрей-Сердюк's problem: it will trim `\u00a0`, because  `\s` matches Unicode non-breaking spaces too
- `/u` modifier (PCRE_UTF8) tells PCRE to handle subject as UTF8-string
- `\x00` matches null-byte characters to mimic default `trim()` function behavior

---

Accepted @Андрей-Сердюк `trim()` answer will mess with multibyte strings.

Example:

```
// This works:
echo trim(' Hello ', ' '.chr(0xC2).chr(0xA0)); 
// > "Hello" 

// And this doesn't work:
echo trim('  Solidarietà  ', ' '.chr(0xC2).chr(0xA0)); 
// > "Solidariet?" -- invalid UTF8 character sequense

// This works for both single-byte and multi-byte sequenses:
echo preg_replace('/^[\s\x00]+|[\s\x00]+$/u', '', ' Hello ');
// > "Hello"
echo preg_replace('/^[\s\x00]+|[\s\x00]+$/u', '', ' Solidarietà '); 
// > "Solidarietà"
```

Comment: After 4h of searching around, this seems to be the solution to go with!

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$string = '" Adv "';
$noSpace = preg_replace('/\s/', '', $string);
```

?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: It makes my string null and delete all spaces between other words if that exists.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the accepted solution *for years* and **I've been wrong all this time**. If I can find this solution in 2022, others too, so please change the accepted solution to the one from @e1v who was right all this time.

**You SHOULD NOT DO THIS!**

```
echo trim('Au delà', ' '.chr(0xC2).chr(0xA0));
```

As it corrupts the UTF-8 encoding:

> Au del�

Note that a "modern" (PHP 7) way to write this could be:

```
echo trim('Au delà', " \u{a0}");//This is WRONG, don't do it!
```

Personally, when I have to deal with *non breakable spaces* (Unicode 00A0, UTF8 C2A0) in strings, I replace the trailing/ending ones by *regular spaces* (Unicode 0020, UTF8 20), and then trim the string. Like this:

```
echo trim(preg_replace('/^\s+|\s+$/u', ' ', "Au delà\u{a0}"));
```

(I would have post a comment or just vote the answer up, but I can't).

Answer (score -1):

```
$str = '<span class="left_corner"> </span><span class="text">Adv</span><span class="right_corner"> </span>';
$rgx = '#(<[^>]+>)|(\s+)#';
$cleaned_str = preg_replace( $rgx, '' , $str );
echo '['. $cleaned_str .']';
```

Comment: It makes my string as null. And with for other strings it delete all spaces between words.